# ASP.NET MVC 5: single controller method to handle paths in file browser mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvcroutehandler

I want to have some controller with the single method that would allow me to navigate through some hierarchy (file system etc.).

In other words I want to have possibility to access this method with flexible routes and get part of routes as parameter. For example in case of this hierarchy

```
Root
  Sub-folder-A
  Sub-folder-B
    Sub-folder-C
```

I want to have access folders with the next routes

```
mymvcapplication/explorer/root
mymvcapplication/explorer/root/sub-folder-a
mymvcapplication/explorer/root/sub-folder-b/sub-folder-c
```

What and where should I configure to implement it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To support variable number of url parameter values in the request url, you can mark your method parameter with `*` prefix in the route definition.

With MVC Attribute routing,

```
[Route("explorer/root/{*levels}")]
public ActionResult Details(string levels = "")
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(levels))
    {
        //request for root
    }
    else
    {
        var levelArray = levels.Split('/');
        //check level array and decide what to do 
    }
    return Content("Make sure to return something valid :) ");
}
```

The last parameter prefixed with `*` is like a ***catch-all*** parameter which will store anything in the url after `explorer/root`

So when you request `yoursite.com/explorer/root/a/b/c/d` , the default model binder will map the value `"a/b/c/d"` to the `levels` parameter. You can call the `Split` method on that string to get an array of url segments.

To enable attribute routing, go to `RouteConfig.cs` and call the `MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` method in the `RegisterRoutes`.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }  
    );
}
```