# ASP MVC route all requests for a controller to the Index action?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a public page that has client side routing. I would like all urls of the form `Public/*` to be routed to `PublicController/Index`.

I tried this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Public",
                url: "Public/{clientRoute}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Public", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

and this works for urls of type `Public/someRoute` but does not work for a url of the form `Public/someRoute/secondRoute` or for `Public/someRoute/secondRoute/thirdRoute` etc.

Comment: Not very sure what you are after. But if you are thinking about having variable number of url params, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573103/asp-net-mvc-5-single-controller-method-to-handle-paths-in-file-browser-mode/34573450#34573450 ?

Comment: If you're using MVC > 5 then you can define the attribute routing on specific actions to support such behavior.

Comment: You can try using IIS module URLRewrite to rewrite the URL's.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were really close!  This should take care of what you are looking to do.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Public",
                url: "Public/{*clientRoute}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Public", action = "Index"}
            );
```

Note the star in the URL parameter, this tells it to function as a "catch all".  Now, anything starting with Public/ will go to this controller/action.  Also, if you don't need the id parameter, don't concern yourself with specifying a default for it.